# Dask concatenate causes memory error , when pandas concatenate does not for same files

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am trying to concatenate several dask dataframes, but this causes all of my RAM to be used up and makes my enviroment (Google Colab) crash.

I have tried concatenating with Dask because I heard Dask partitions the files so that it loads into memory easier. However, Pandas is able to handle his operation, where as Dask does not.

The reason I am using Dask is because when I try to save my Pandas dataframe, my enviroment crashes. So I am trying to see if Dask is able to save my data without crashing, but I am stuck on creating my dataframe.

```
combA = np.load(file2A.format(0) , allow_pickle=True)
combB = np.load(file2B.format(0), allow_pickle=True )
combC = np.load(file2C.format(0), allow_pickle=True )
combD = np.load(file2D.format(0) , allow_pickle=True)
combE = np.load(file2E.format(0) , allow_pickle=True )
combF = np.load(file2F.format(0), allow_pickle=True )

dfAllA = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(combA), npartitions=10)
dfAllB = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(combB), npartitions=10)
dfAllC = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(combC), npartitions=10)
dfAllD = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(combD), npartitions=10)
dfAllE = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(combE), npartitions=10)
dfAllF = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(combF), npartitions=10)

dfAllT = dd.concat([dfAllA, dfAllB, dfAllC, dfAllD, dfAllE, dfAllF ], interleave_partitions=True)
```

I would like to execute the concatenation without a memory error.

From the answer below, it looks like I should define a function that performs the loading and concatenation of the date, input that into dask.delayed functions, and do .compute() on those functions

Something like

```
def daskFunc1():

    combA = np.load(file2A.format(0) , allow_pickle=True)
    combB = np.load(file2B.format(0), allow_pickle=True )
    combC = np.load(file2C.format(0), allow_pickle=True )
    combD = np.load(file2D.format(0) , allow_pickle=True)
    combE = np.load(file2E.format(0) , allow_pickle=True )
    combF = np.load(file2F.format(0), allow_pickle=True )

    dfAllA = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(combA), npartitions=10)
    dfAllB = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(combB), npartitions=10)
    dfAllC = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(combC), npartitions=10)
    dfAllD = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(combD), npartitions=10)
    dfAllE = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(combE), npartitions=10)
    dfAllF = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(combF), npartitions=10)

def daskFunc2():
    dfAllT = dd.concat([dfAllA, dfAllB, dfAllC, dfAllD, dfAllE, dfAllF ], interleave_partitions=True)

from dask.delayed import delayed

f1 = delayed(daskFunc1)
f2 = delayed(daskFunc2)

f1.compute()
f2.compute()
```

however, when I then tried

`dfAllT.head()`

I get

`NameError: name 'dfAllT' is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

You are currently loading all of your data into RAM, and then handing it to Dask.  Dask can not help you much if all of your data is already filling up RAM when it first starts.

Instead, it is much nicer to tell Dask how to load your data, and let it do the loading at the right time.  This document might point you in the right direction: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-collections.html and here is an old example https://gist.github.com/mrocklin/e7b7b3a65f2835cda813096332ec73ca

Comment: From reading those sources, it looks like I should define a function that performs the loading and concatenation of the date, input that into dask.delayed functions, and do .compute() on those functions. However, this isn't quite working out. I updated my question to post the code I tried.